# How to declare a vector of llist of string and process it?

Tags: c++, string, list, vector, stl

I am new in c++. I have tried the following but i am getting error please correct me.

```
vector<list<string>> ques(size);  //initialization
cout<<ques[pos].front()<<endl;    //printing out the top element at pos
vector<list<string>>::iterator it;
for(it=ques[pos].begin();it!=ques[pos].end();it++) //traversing through the list at pos <getting error>          
{
                cout<<*it;           
}
```

---

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::list<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > > >}’ and ‘std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >}’)|
```

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Are you expecting everyone to guess what the compilation error is, for the code that's mostly not even shown?

Comment: Is this *all* your code, or do you also have some `#include`s and a `main()` function?

Comment: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::list<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > > >}’ and ‘std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >}’)|

Comment: for transversing through the list

Comment: @NeerajSinghAithani [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39064844/edit) to add such additional information. In comments it turns out not to be useful. Even better as mentioned, post a [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over a `std::list<std::string>`.

This means that your iterator should be:

```
list<string>::iterator it;
```

and not:

```
vector<list<string>>::iterator it;
```

This would be for iterating over the vector itself.

Furthermore, it's even better to use modern C++, which makes the compiler figure this out, all by itself:

```
for(auto it=ques[pos].begin(); it!=ques[pos].end(); it++)
```

and even better:

```
for (auto &value: ques[pos])
     cout << value;
```